# Viewport Not Working Correctly

Tags: css, responsiveness

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Website displays great in Chromes mobile resize testing, but not so well on an actual iphone 6.

https://aloharestorationco.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try to prevent zoom on all mobiles, i think this may help you.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```